# DrawImage will not load on first frame

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a simple draw image for my canvas but it won't display on the first frame.

It's driving me mad i dunno why it won't do it!!

This is my script:

```
img = new Image();
img.src = 'images/0.png'; //preLoad the image


window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       || 
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    || 
          window.oRequestAnimationFrame      || 
          window.msRequestAnimationFrame     || 
          function( callback,  element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})(); //frames per second


function gameUpdate(){ 
    previous = 0;
    requestAnimFrame( gameUpdate ); 
    draw(); 
}
```

Then the `draw()` function has this:

```
//doesn't display on first fame
canvas['canvas1'].ctx.drawImage(img, 100, 150); 

//displays on first frame           
canvas['canvas1'].ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
canvas['canvas1'].ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);
```

FillRect works fine but not the drawImage for the first frame, any ideas why this might be ??

Comment: Are you sure the image is loaded the first time?

Comment: Not totally sure, but i gathered assigning it to img.src would of preLoaded it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start the animation loop by calling `requestAnimFrame` *outside* of your `gameUpdate` function

```
requestAnimFrame(gameUpdate)
```

You might also need to make sure the image is actually loaded

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    // do the draw image here
}
img.src = 'images/0.png'; //preLoad the image
```

Comment: gameUpdate is called from a windows Onload, the fillRect displays on the first frame so that is working fine.

Comment: I tried it with a loop to preLoad a number of images like this:
http://pastebin.com/f5wL8jjU  still doesn't display on first frame how ever.

Comment: make sure the `img.src` part is *outside* of the `img.onload` event, also please add any other relevant code to the question itself

Comment: Ah okay i think for my preLoading function using objects might be better off a new question :)